# How to use multiple Microsoft Forms for a Quiz?

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365-apps

I am creating a Quiz application using Microsoft Forms (Quiz type) for the survey industry. For my intended Quiz using Microsft Forms, the questions are ideally need to be randomly fetched up from 10 different sections (Section 1, Section 2, Section 3 and so on) where each section has it's own form containing approx. 20-40 questions. So in short this master Quiz Form will fetch 100 random questions from those 10 section based forms.

Alternative source where all raw questions required for these 10 sections could be stored might be a single or multiple json files, Excel or Google spreadsheet where we could make a joint application using Flow and Forms.

Would it be possible?